# How to apply multiple ordering to firebase query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in database.

```
  "globalContestID":  {
        "1181855391902492":
              {
                points: 123456789
                timestamp: 123456789
              },
         "123456742234324":
              {
                points: 1323344234
                timestamp: 122441434
              }  }
```

I'm trying to get top 10 scores in past week or month etc. I need to get the data between start time and end time and then sort based on points to get top 10.

This returns NULL:

```
mContestTableName.orderByChild("timestamp")
    .startAt(starttime).endAt(endtime)
    .orderByChild("points")
    .limitToLast(10) { }
```

If I remove the "points" part, the query returns all data, So data is fine.

What am I doing wrong in the query?

Comment: I don't think you can `orderByChild` more than once, at least not without overriding the first ones.

Comment: You can only have a single `orderBy...` clause in a Firebase Database query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: orderByChild("timestamp") i don't need that. Its only to get the startAt endAt query. I want to order only by top 10 points.

Comment: Okay, then why did you order by it? Or are you just telling me the solution you have?

Comment: I want to apply startAt endAt to "timestamp". I do not know how to refer to timestamp values to do that to apply those time frame.
Something like mContestTableName. [some reference to child]("timestamp")
    .startAt(starttime).endAt(endtime)
    .orderByChild("points")
    .limitToLast(10) { }

Comment: I think Frank here is the better person to ask about that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any idea how to achieve this

Comment: You're trying to filter on date range and then get the top 10 scores. That requires two `orderBy` clauses, which is not supported in Firebase queries.